# Solving DL4J compilation error

Tags: dl4j

I am trying to download DL4J source without error.

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

I cloned https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j.git

and imported using existing Maven project in Eclipse.

Tons of dependencies are downloaded but it's bombarded with errors.

Anyone who knows which branch version is free of compile error?

The site says 0.9.1 is most stable version, but it still generates errors.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a few things here:

1. No major open source project in today's day and age operates without a build system. This can be maven,gradle,sbt,..
2. You ignored all of our docs about building from source and the like. You don't need to do that. Use the build system like it's intended.

My suggestion here:

Learn what the rest of the java world did and use maven:
Our quick start is here: http://deeplearning4j.org/quickstart

Follow our examples for the latest versions:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples

Chances are you do not need to build from source (this involves 5 other projects you probably do not want to do that) - but if you absolutely must be prepared to use c++ among other things.

The guide for that can be found here:
https://deeplearning4j.org/devguide

Comment: I don't complain DL4J using maven. And I've already played with dl4j-examples and quick start stuffs without problem. I just wanted to find out inner work of UI server. Let me try again anyway. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to build from source - follow our dev guide. 

As for eclipse/maven.. like I said: Follow your standard maven/eclipse guide: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-update-my-maven-project-to-work-in-eclipse.html - I can only guess what your problems might have been there.

Chances are eclipse has out of date metadata. Usually it's solved with reimport. Beyond that...it's great you want to do that but try to understand that when you want to get in to the internals please look a bit in to the docs for building from source.